# Replacing define statement with actual code

Tags: c++, inline, constexpr

I know that `#define` is not really good to use, I am not sure if that's a duplicate but I couldn't find what's the best way is to do this:

I have a program that uses a definition like:

```
#define True GetObject(true)
```

I need to replace the define statement with actual code

but I can't think of a way to make it so the following code:

```
int main() {

  auto c = True;

  return 0;
}
```

turns into this at compile time:

```
int main() {

  auto c = GetObject(true);

  return 0;
}
```

Summary:
I want an exact replacement of "define" as code, I found something like an inline function
could help, but is there a way to make an inline variable?

I tried the following but ended up with an error

```
inline Object True = GetObject(true);
```

***NOTE***: I can't make Object/GetObject a constexpr class

***NOTE 2***: I'd like to avoid turning `True` to `True()` if that's possible

This is basically a question for educational purposes but I would like to use it in a small library I am writing, If you could tell me what would be the best way to do this I'd be really happy

Thanks!!!

***EDIT 1***

As the first above is not quite clear, I'd like True to call `GetObject(true)` function every time

The returned value is going to be the same but the function call is necessary

***EDIT 2***

I didn't think it is necessary to explain this but, the library I am creating is a simple layer (that's not really important for this),

The macro name `True` is completely random, it could be named something completely different (I am just using it for testing)

The macro is used to create a Class that I need to use a lot in my code and I also need it to create a new instance of the class (not just a copy)

I also need to update the class a lot so to add more constants in the constructor I would need to have some simple way to do, I don't think it would be good to go in each of my 10 headers/sources and replace every instance

with the values that represent 'True' and other states.

the part about removing () is because I don't think it's convenient to see a lot of parenthesis in something that looks like a variable (or maybe some kind of compile-time constant?)

Comment: Please, dont write a library where `True` means something "magical". Does `GetObject(true)` return exactly the same thing every time it's called? Would `const auto& True = GetObject(true);` be an option?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, in my library there is a whole class, but I don't think it's needed to write here, and yes, GetObject(true) returns a "Custom" boolean object that's set to true (initialy)

Comment: I would like to add more states and True is just a test name, I will rename it as I develop the library

Comment: @TedLyngmo Will that have the same effect as replacing the macro? I would like it to have as possibly less overhead as possible (but should every time create a new object)

Comment: why do you want to avoid `GetObject(true)` in the first place? When thats the function that is actually called I dont see the benefit of hiding this in the code

Comment: btw `#define` is not bad. Misusing `#define` is bad. If you want to write C++ code that doesnt look like C++ code, then `define` is your friend ;)

Comment: I think that it's easier to have a specific name if you want something like a switch class, you have a name for each state and I think that's easier to understand in some cases (and maybe use) than let's say remember that 1 = a specific state, 2 = another state and so on

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number So you say that I should just use define?

Comment: if thats what you really want. Well, no. I am saying you should write `GetObject(true)`. Thats the exact replacement for using the macro. Simply do not use the macro and call the function.

Comment: btw the question is unclear. The macro calls a function but you are asking for an inline variable. Should each occurence of `True` call the function? Or should each occurence of `True` get the same value?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry for not being clear, I'll edit the question

Comment: Just get rid of the `#define`(s) and write the code in a straightforward fashion.  Your future self will thank you for it.

Comment: You need a global variable called True. Either of type `Object`, and your copy constructor (not copy assignment!) creates a new object, or of another type and you create a new object each time it implicitly converts. Is it a good idea? Probably only for educational reasons trying things out.

Comment: its not clear what you want to achieve by using the macro. Why do you not write the code that you want to write in the first place? ie write `GetObject(true);` directly and forget about `True`. Its a poor name and the macro does nothing useful. Macros and `#define` can be used to do actually useful stuff. I don't see that here. (though maybe there is something you didnt explain yet)

Comment: @PaulSanders wouldn't define be easier to modify if needed? If for some reason I need to do ```True = GetObject(false)``` I think it would be way quicker to do if GetObject is used way too many times

Comment: editors have search and replace. Its not harder to modify `True` than it is to modify `GetObject(true)`. Anyhow its a function, if you want to change what the function does you need to only change the one function

Comment: C and C++ normally have parantheses to call something. We do not understand, whether you see `True` as a function call or a singleton object or a value to compare with. I commented one option how to get, what you directly specified, but what you plan seems to be irregular at least, so we would need to know more to give you a deeper recommendation.

Comment: @user18812922, for the purpose of easier modification you may just declare you function  with default argument value: ` sometype GetObject(bool input = true)`

Comment: @user18812922 Code should, above all, be readable and maintainable.  What you are suggesting is neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is probably similar in principle to your code.
It is solved with `#define` and sets a `serialno` to each `Object` and prints something out to the console:

```
#define True GetObject(true)
#define False GetObject(false)

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Object {
public:
    Object(bool b, int serial) : _b(b), _serialno(serial) {};

    bool _b;
    int _serialno;
};

Object GetObject(bool b) {
    static int curserial = 0;

    Object result(b, ++curserial);

    cout << "Created Object with serialno " << result._serialno << " and value " << boolalpha << result._b << endl;
    return result;
}

int main() {
    auto c = True;
    auto d = True;
    auto e = False;

    return 0;
}
```

which generates the output

```
Created Object with serialno 1 and value true
Created Object with serialno 2 and value true
Created Object with serialno 3 and value false
```

Now we change it to the same result without '#define':

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Object;
void GotObject(Object& o);

class Object {
public:
    Object(bool b) : _b(b), _serialno(++curserial) {};
    Object(const Object& other) : _b(other._b), _serialno(++curserial) {
        GotObject(*this);
    };

    bool _b;
    int _serialno;

    inline static int curserial = 0;
};

void GotObject(Object& o) {
    cout << "Created Object with serialno " << o._serialno << " and value " << boolalpha << o._b << endl;
}

inline Object True(true);
inline Object False(false);

int main() {
    auto c = True;
    auto d = True;
    auto e = False;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Created Object with serialno 3 and value true
Created Object with serialno 4 and value true
Created Object with serialno 5 and value false
```

Each time we assign the values of `True` or `False` to new variables the copy constructor is called and can do, whatever you did in `GetObject`.

Small variant: If we choose this alternative custom constructor instead of the one in the code,

```
    Object(bool b) : _b(b), _serialno(0) {};
```

we would get as output:

```
Created Object with serialno 1 and value true
Created Object with serialno 2 and value true
Created Object with serialno 3 and value false
```

The difference is, whether the `serialno` is also counted up for `True` and `False` themselves or only after assigning those to a variable.

For Generating `True` and `False` the first constructor is called, for the following assignments to other variables, the second constructor.

You could also keep a `bool _original` variable inside `Object` to only call `GetObject()`, which states whether you copy from the original `True` or `False`. It is true only for `True` and `False`. You can recognize those by them calling a special constructor. If you want to make it safe to use, you can make that constructor private, so it can only be called by friend functions or by static factory methods.

In the following code, GotObject is not called from assigning from `c` to `f`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Object;
void GotObject(Object& o);

class Object {
public:
    Object(bool b) : _b(b), _serialno(0), _original(true) {};
    Object(const Object& other) : _b(other._b), _original(false), _serialno(0) {
        if (other._original)
            GotObject(*this);
    };

    bool _original;
    bool _b;
    int _serialno;
};

void GotObject(Object& o) {
    static int curserial = 0;
    o._serialno = ++curserial;

    cout << "Created Object with serialno " << o._serialno << " and value " << boolalpha << o._b << endl;
}

inline Object True(true);
inline Object False(false);

int main() {
    auto c = True;
    auto d = True;
    auto e = False;
    auto f = c;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Created Object with serialno 1 and value true
Created Object with serialno 2 and value true
Created Object with serialno 3 and value false
```

Answer (score 1):

> but is there a way to make an inline variable?

Yes, since C++17 it's possible to define inline variables. Inline variables are same as other namespace scope variables, except you can define them in a header that may be included into more than one translation unit. Example:

```
inline auto True = GetObject(true);
```

> I want an exact replacement of "define" as code

A variable won't behave in the exactly same way as the macro replacement. The `GetObject` function will be called only once to initialise the variable, as opposed to every time when the macro expands to a function call.

If you want to have a function call, then the ideal solution is to explicitly write a function call, with the parentheses that are part of the syntax.

> NOTE 2: I'd like to avoid turning True to True() if that's possible

This is a bad thing to want if you want to make a function call. I recommend giving up one of your desires.

Comment: I have read that the compiler copy-pastes a whole inline function when it's called. Does that not apply to inline variables?

Comment: If the copy constructor is customized, code can be executed. It will be a new instance anyway.

Comment: @Sebastian More likely you need a proxy object and a conversion operator to whatever type `GetObject(true)` returns. But that then breaks `auto x = True;`

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like `True` to call `GetObject(true)` function every time

Then `True()` is the best you can get without macros.

Alternatively, if you're going to be calling methods on the resulting instance, make them free functions and let them create an instance for themselves:

```
namespace True
{
    void foo()
    {
        TrueObj obj(true);
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
True::foo();
```

Comment: That's also a pretty good way to handle this, I'll take a look at these 2 answers and if I find that your answer is better (for my case) I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: One can use conversion operators to get `bool c = True;` to call `GetObject(true)`, but not with `auto`. I've often pondered if C++ should have an `operator auto()` for this sort of case. It makes all sorts of neat witchcraft work better.